# Specify ipython profile qtconsole

Tags: ipython, jupyter, qtconsole

Any guesses on how to specify a specific ipython config from qtconsole?

Without qtconsole:

```
ipython --profile=my_profile_name
```

Where my_profile_name is a profile name under your global ipython directory, for ipython kernel options. This lets you specify ipython-specific things, like modules to import on load.

With qtconsole:

```
jupyter console --config=/./jupyter_qtconsole_config.py
```

Where you can specify a specific config file to setup general non-ipython-specific qtconsole settings, like font size.

How can you specify set the ipython profile (ideally point it to a file, but may be limited to specifying a global profile name) from qtconsole? ie add the ---profile tag to jupyter qtconsole? Im this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/kzEws9ZeCFE Matthias mentions specifying a kernel, but that seems overkill.

You can specify profile in a file called 'ipython_kernel_config.py'; perhaps the solution lies in launching qtconsole with --config=jupyter_qtconsole_config.py, and pointing in this file to a custom ipython_kernel_config.py that points to a profile name; not sure how to point to the kernel config file, and no obvious way in the jupyter config docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom `kernelspec` and launch the qtconsole for this specific kernel.

Usually a "kernel" is seen as a language; this is an extremely restrictive view of what a kernel is. In your case what you want to do is have multipel IPython kernels, each launching IPython with a different profile. [Here](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html) is the more formal definition of what a kernelspec is; but roughly it describe how to start a process.

By using `jupyter kernelspec list`, I can see I have a Python kernelspec in `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`; let's have a look at it, and in particular the `kernel.json` file:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "$HOME/anaconda/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Now you just need to duplicate all of that, and add `"--profile=my_profile_name"` in the `"argv"` list. Don't forget to give a different name to the Folder and and change `"display_name": "Python 3"` to `"display_name": "Python 3 (my_profile)"`; once this is available. just launch a qtconsole, a notebook or anything else with this kernel, and you should get your new profile.

You can of course use utilities like [a2km](https://github.com/minrk/a2km) to do that programmatically from the command line.

Comment: Thanks! I then just needed to make a new folder under jupyter/kernels named appropriately, place the file you described in it, and launch with 'jupyter qtconsole --kernel myfoldername'

Comment: Another solution: Run qtconsole from a location that contains an ipython_config.py file; this will override other profiles.